# php image uploading safety against hackers

Tags: php, html, security

how safe the following code is, in case everybody could make use of it:

```
$file = $_FILES["file"]['tmp_name'];
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
$base64 = base64_encode($contents);
<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.$base64.'">
```

in case this is not safe agains hackers, etc. how should i secure it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Char set of a base64 encoded string is `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx yz0123456789+/` and an `=` sign as a last byte filter.

So no matter what the file contents is, you are putting its base64 encoded value and even without escaping, browser will show the given string in the `img` tag.

You will however need to make sure that the string actually encodes to an image.

And by the way, you are wasting a *lot* of your server memory for this task by assigning a new variable in every step.